# Почему компьютер долго исполняет функцию

Tags: python, скорость

```
def func():
    i = 1
    while i < 10**5:
        print(i)
        i += 1
        
func()

%timeit func() >> 18 сек
```

18 сек на обработку 100 000 итераций это не слишком долго?
Если это за пределами нормы, тогда в чем может быть дело?
Система такая: проц i5 на время выполнения кода загружается с 7 до 50%, память ddr3 14gb загружена на 60% без изменений.

Comment: операция print очень долгая, ей надо вызывать ОС для вывода в консоль. А вызов ОС - это переключение контекста, которое само по себе очень долгое. Плюс к этому сама косоль очень тормозная штука

Comment: да сделал во так: def func():
    i = 1
    while i < 10**5:
        i += 1
    return i
        
func() Время составило 5,5 мск

Comment: Там ещё и преобразование int в str для печати время жрёт, но основное конечно вывод на консоль, да

Comment: Когда возникают такие вопросы, стоит воспользоваться [встроенным профилировщиком](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html).